# Use for every Reyling Party seperate client Certificate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on, wif

I'm reading up on SSO and I used this tutorial http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx for creating a custom STS.

If I understood correct on the STS machine is installed a certificate. The reyling party sends the thumbprint of the x509 signature. So the relying party will accept only claims of a STS with the proper certificate. Is this correct?

If so, I would like to implement that every relying party is sending a certificate to the STS which the STS got installed too. On a request the STS look up in his trusted relying party list if the sent certificate is known by the STS.

Is this implemention a good idea and is this good practice? Is there a good ressource to implement this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implementing a custom STS is hard work.  I would advise you to have a look at windows azure ACS or the Thinktecture free STS as a starting point.
This being said, having a separate certificate for a relying party is a common practice.  However, the private key of this certificate is normally stored inside some database in the STS (ACS and Thinktecture both support this).  The relying party only knows the public key.
The security token (SAML2 or JWT) is then signed by the acs with the security token and the relying party can use the public key (or a thumbprint) to verify the signature.
Please also notice that a SAML2 token can also be encrypted (next to being signed) and that you can use a different certificate for that.
I personally would recommend using a seperate certificate it the STS (or your organisation) has some kind of website were "anybody" can register their application as a relying party.  If all your elying parties are "internal" applications I would at least consider using a single certificate to sign all security tokens.  This has the advantage that you can publish the (public) key in your Federation meta data document (located at FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml).  If you wish to update the key, you can update it there (by first publishing new and old key there and later only the new key).  Relying parties can then update there keys based on this meta data (adfs uses a similar approach).
So bottom line : having a seperate certificate per RP is good but having a single one (for signing - not encryption) is much easier to update.